# Access AWS RDS from Private Subnet

Tags: mysql, security, amazon-web-services, subnet, rds

I created an AWS VPC with public and private subnet.

I created an RDS(MySQL) inside private subnet. I want to access the RDS from internet (From my home machine).

I have kept the flag Publicly Accessible Yes.
Also in the RDS security group, I tried to open port3306 for all IPs (I know not recommended but still) as well tried all ports with all IPs (the worst security ..I know) and tried to access but nothing worked.
I can access the RDS from bastion machine created in public subnet but from internet I can not.

Do you think, am I required any other setting?

I verified ACL and they are fine too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot access instances in a private subnet from the internet - that is the point of a private subnet.

Either access it thru the bastion machine, or put it in the public subnet.

Edit:

There is a good description of different options [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.html#USER_VPC.Hiding).  If you put your RDS instance into a private subnet, then it is not accessible from the internet.  So if you need access from the internet, it must be placed in a public subnet.

Comment: I think you can access. When I read the article at docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/… which says you are required to enable DNS Hostname as well ensure RDS is publicly Accessible. Even it points to docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/… which says similar.

Comment: I find the example in the doc unclear too. After many googling, I finally found the doc that explicitly says public subnets are required for the option to work. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Authorizing.Network.html

Answer (score 3):

Very late response, but you could set up a bastion server in the public subnet and set up an ssh tunnel through that bastion server.

Answer (score 0):

if the RDS was in private subnet:

AWS Doc:
At the present time, updating an existing DB Subnet Group does not change the current subnet of the deployed DB instance; an instance-type scale operation is required. Explicitly changing the DB Subnet Group of a deployed DB instance is not currently allowed.

There is two options after you change the DB Subnet Group:
Option 1) Delete / take final snapshot of the RDS & restore the snapshot with the public subnet. (as in 2016 July)

Option 2) Change instance type scale to large then small again

Comment: Can you please link to the AWS documentation you are referencing?